# Mouse Events on Controls

Tags: vba, ms-access, onclick, onmousemove

In Access 2010, I built a calendar. I'm sprucing it up some now and was wondering if there was a "cleaner" way of coding a couple things.

I have a couple of functions:
`Mousey()` --> Changes the cursor to your standard finger pointer (which isn't included in the standard Access/VBA library).

`ClickDay(intClick As Integer)` --> Allows user to go into that day for more details

On my calendar, I have 6 rows, with 7 days on each row. Each day calls the `Mousey()` function `_MouseMove` and the `ClickDay()` function on `_Click()`.

What I'm doing right now is creating an Event Procedure for all 42 `_Click()` that calls my `ClickDay` function and ANOTHER 42 Event Procedures for `_MouseMove` that calls my `Mousey` function.

Obviously, that's 84 procedures (at 3 lines each) that I'd like to slim down.

Can anyone think of a way to Put each function in one procedure with a loop of some sort? Here are my functions:

```
Private Function ClickDay(intClick As Integer)
    'Function that is called when one of the number boxes are clicked
    Dim intYear As Integer
    Dim intMonth As Integer
    Dim intDay As Integer

    'Get the pieces of the date based on box that is clicked
    intYear = lblYear.Caption
    intMonth = ChangeToMonth(lblMonth.Caption)
    intDay = Me("t" & intClick).Value
    'change global variable
    gintDate = DateSerial(intYear, intMonth, intDay)
    'go to the date clicked
    DoCmd.OpenForm ("frmToday")
End Function
```

and

```
Public Function Mousey()
    Dim hCur As Long

    hCur = LoadCursor(0, IDC_HAND)
    If (hCur > 0) Then
        SetCursor hCur
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: You could use some sort of control arrays? See [this](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/05/vba-control-arrays/)

Comment: Glad it helped. If you want, you can post your final solution here and accept it as an answer so that it may help future visitors :)

Comment: I decided not to rewrite the code due to time restraints on this project and just kept what I had. If I come across a situation like this again, I'll be sure to come back to this post and share some code.